Homeomorphisms between open unit $n$-balls
Problem(s): Let $B^n$ denote the (open) unit $n$-ball centered at the origin. Show (a) $B^n\cong (-1,1)^n$ and (b) $B^k\times B^{n-k}\cong B^n$, for $0\leq k\leq n$, where $B^0=\mathbb R^0=\{0\}$. Here $\mathbb R^n$ has the standard topology induced by the Euclidean metric.
So far: For (a) I can show $B^n\cong \mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^n\cong (-1,1)^n$, so the result follows, but this feels a bit clumsy so does anyone have a quicker way of showing it without the intermediate step? For (b) I'm stuck on thinking of a suitable map to act as the homeomorphism, any tips or a direct way/result this follows from?

For point (b) notice that $B^k\times B^{n-k}\cong (-1,1)^k\times (-1,1)^{n-k}=(-1,1)^n\cong B^n$.

There's nothing clumsy about applying a good theorem: Every composition of homeomorphisms is a homeomorphism.

More generally, any non-empty bounded (I think bounded isn't needed but I've added it just to be sure) convex open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to the open ball. The proof is by using projections. b) follows from a) and how homeomorphisms act with respect to products

Thanks, got it!

For (a) note that $B^n$ and $(-1,1)^n$ are the open unit balls with respect to the Euclidean and the $\max$-norm, respectively, Now have a look at the construction in   https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3514374/349785.

Here's how I'd define a homeomorphism directly, though I think it's debatable whether this is more clumsy than the composition of homeomorphisms you describe:
For each non-origin point $p \in (-1,1)^n$, let $d(p)$ be the length of the straight-line segment from the origin, passing through $p$, to the boundary of $(-1,1)^n$. Define
$$h(p) = \frac{p}{d(p)},$$
for points that are not the origin and
$$h(0,...0) = (0,...,0)$$
I'll leave it as an exercise to prove this is a homeomorphism. One could probably come up with an explicit formula for $d(p)$, but it would be relatively messy and I don't think it's needed for the proof.
